# Migrating database from oracle 11.2.0.03 to 11.2.0.04.

Tags: oracle

I have been assigned task of migrating our oracle database from 11.2.0.03 to 11.2.0.04 version. Being new to oracle, I have list down all activities I need to carry out to make it successful. I will be creating new database in newer version and creating dump of my present database and export that to newer versions. 
I have listed down below activity for same :

1. Need to take dump data from Existing  databases to new DEV, UAT and PROD databases.(Sequences also needs to be refreshed)

My confusion is, do I need to take care of more scenarios. Since I am not DBA, just a programmer, maybe I am missing some critical points.

Comment: What is the reason of your company to migrate a whole database system just for a minor release? That minor release bug fix may even be useless to your current settings.

Comment: @Vhortex: There  are always good reasons to upgrade to the latest version of a release. For Oracle 11g this is 11.2.0.4. 11.2.0.3 isn't fully supported since August 2015. No patches will be released for 11.2.0.3 anymore, especially no quarterly security patches will be released. You shouldn't wait with the upgrade until you run into problems with the current version. At present direct upgrade from 11.2.0.2 to 12c is possible. But for 10g direct upgrade is only possible for 10.2.0.5, this is the lates 10g version. Similar will happen for the upgrade from 11g to 12.2 or 13.

Comment: I agree the statement given by miracle173. @ubaid You can search My Oracle Support Knowledge documents for better planning for the upgrading. There are long check list that you should consider before upgrading. And most important is thing is test before going production.

Comment: I second the comments to reference documents on MOS.  In general, you should forget the export/import.  Install the 11.2.0.4 (it is a full install even though it is classified as a patchset) into a new ORACLE_HOME and use the Database Upgrade Assistant (dbua) to upgrade the existing database.  That's the high-level view.  You need to read the upgrade guide and any other relevant docs from MOS.  I find it troubling that this is not assigned to a DBA.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to look at the Oracle patching advisor (in Oracle parlance this is a patch, not an upgrade, as you're updating to a new patch set):

Doc ID: [331.1](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=331.1) (My Oracle Support login required)